# Filter Keywords with Column that created

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have just created Column , but this is not from database. I would like to filter in only those with 'PAR_SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED' from the Column that created "PAR_Status_Flight".

[image]

I would like to filter in only those with'PAR_SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED' from the created "PAR_Status_Flight". "PAR_Status_Flight" is not from the database.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: One reason is that I can't read that tiny image text on my laptop.

Comment: Do you mean `select * from "foundry_sync"."PAR_1" where "PAR_Status_Flight" = case when "Date" between "new__actual_time" and "new__actual_time_a" then 'PAR_SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED' else 'PAR_FAILED TO BE GENERATED' end;`? The query you're showing isn't ordered right and the status you're using as a literal in your `where` has nothing to do with the case you specified in `select`. You could've assumed you can't use a `case` in `where` and/or in a `=` comparison; you can. Also, it's good to maintain uniform capitalisation and spacing - you're mixing spaces with underscores, uppercase, lowercase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use  of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap it as an in-line view like the following:

```
select * from
(select case when "Date" between "new__actual_time" and "new__actual_time_a"
            then 'PAR_SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED'
    else 'PAR_FAILED TO BE GENERATED' end as "PAR_Status_Flight"
    from "foundry_sync"."PAR_1")
where "PAR_Status_Flight" = 'PAR_SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED'
```